# No descriptive error when trying to post an answer while logged out

Tags: feature-request, answers, session

While typing an answer, my session expired (?) causing me to be logged out.

I didn't notice that, but when pressing 'Post your answer', the following 'error' was shown:

> Your answer couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

<sup>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a368s.png)</sup>

Unfortunately, there is no 'error above'; I expected something like 'your session has expired'.

---

Inspecting the `submit` request, the following JSON was returned:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": {
        "Email": [
            "An email is required to post."
        ]
    },
    "warnings": {},
    "source": {}
}
```

Seems like this additional error is missing.

---

Steps to reproduce:

1. Login to any SE site
2. Open a question
3. Type an awesome answer
4. Delete all your cookies
5. Press 'Post Your Answer'

Comment: Well, there's already "live refresh" going on behind the scenes and checking things like question being closed or deleted, then showing proper message even while you're writing the answer. So ideally, this live refresh can also check if you're still logged in, and if not, show a message and don't let you post. (And making it clear you should save the contents elsewhere before reloading, since draft is attached to the account.)